# iOS: After one animation, all other views start animating

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I have a very peculiar problem. In an iOS app I've developed, after running the animations below I find that various other elements of the UI now animate whenever they appear.

For instance, once these animations below are run, every time I navigate to a new tab in my app, all the UI elements animate from the top left corner of the iphone to their proper positions. I have specified no animations for these UI elements in the other tabs and in fact even elements that I have no access to, like the activity indicator in the iPhone status bar, begin to animate all on their own.

What is going on? Why does this occur only after the animation below is executed? Before running this animation (with a button press) all other UI elements in other app tabs do not animate at all when they appear, which is the expected behaviour.

```
- (IBAction) btnChosenPostcodeClicked:(id)sender {

  //prep animations
  startView.alpha = 1.0;
  postcodeView.alpha = 0.0;

  [self.view addSubview:postcodeView];

  [UIView beginAnimations:@"ChosenPostcodeAnimation01" context:nil];

  [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationSpeed];
  [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.view cache:YES];
  [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
  [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(chosenPostCodeFadeoutAnimationDone:finished:context:)];

  startView.alpha = 0.0;

  [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)chosenPostCodeFadeoutAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    //prep animations
    postcodeView.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ChosenPostcodeAnimation02" context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationSpeed];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.view cache:YES];

    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(42, 157, 239, 180);
    imvBubble.frame = newRect;

    postcodeView.alpha = 1.0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a

```
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

in chosenPostCodeFadeoutAnimationDone so absolutely everything you do is becoming part of the animation!

Comment: Would be awesome with an animation wrapped around an entire app, everything you do gets animated! Hahah.

Comment: Incidentally, there must be another potential cause for this bug in addition to animation blocks as it's happening to me and I don't have a single unclosed block. (iOS6)